# .NET 8.0 Blazor Server app with authentication to external Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I've search the web for a simple tutorial for this but I can't seem to find this exact scenario.

I have the following projects:

**WebApi**
This is a standard .NET 8.0 web api with individual accounts authentication. I've created everything using the microsoft defaults and I'm using the new endpoints created automatically by `app.MapGroup("/account").MapIdentityApi()`. This works fine and I'm able to login and register using postman / swagger

**ApiClient**

This is a class library that handles all the calls to the WebApi including the login, register, etc. This ApiClient library has a method to set the access token before calling the actual method if it required authentication. This is also working fine

Now, what I want to do now is to create a Blazor Server app (I'm new at Blazor) that will provide me an UI for Login (for example) and when the user puts in the username/password it will call the apiClient.Login(...) method with the username and password. What I need to do then is check if I get the correct token and if so store this somewhere on blazor side and tell blazor that I'm authenticated. So when I go to an [Authorized] page in blazor and it requires me to call an api, it will pass the access token stored on login and call the apiClient method I want.

All examples online either use a different authentication JWT token, AAD, etc. or they simple show creating the database and the auth layer all in the Blazor server side. This is not what I need. I need a standalone API using the new IdentityUI endpoints and a way to connect from blazor to that API and keep me logged in, etc.

I think I need to create a custom AuthenticationStateProvider but I still don't understand how can I handle this. Do I use cookie based auth in blazor? Do I rely solely on the api to know I'm logged in? How will the AuthorizedViews in blazor know that I'm authenticated. I assume I have to manually set the user in the HttpContext.User with the claims I get from the API, etc.

Another thing is the 2FA authentication. The generated identity UI endpoint for the login works as follows:
You login with your username / password, you get an 401 error back with the detail "TwoFactorRequired" and you then need to call the same login endpoint with the user / pass and 2fa code. Which means that in the blazor UI I would need to catch that 401, keep the user/pass in a hidden or variable, show the 2FA code page and then call login again with the 3 values. This doesn't seem too secure if I'm storing the username/password in a hidden field just to get the 2FA. Or maybe there is another way to login with 2fa without using the standard UI endpoint.

Can someone point me to a tutorial or give me some lights on how to implement this?

My reason to want to use a independent API is because I want to be able to expose the said API to other devices, etc.

The reason I want to use the default identity UI endpoints is for the management of all the 2FA, recovery codes, refresh tokens, etc. I had a custom logic using JWT tokens in the past and it was a pain to maintain.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Microsoft developer one more technology which is not completed solution. And if you want to have some solid solution - you have to use third party providers like Azure Entra B2C. All that mess with they made in authentication is on purpose. To make simple things - hard. If you want to have something solid - you have to pay.